# How to determine FreeBSD kernel size

Tags: kernel, freebsd

I'm trying to remove some options from GENERIC to reduce kernel size. How can I find kernel size to track the changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, "ls -al /boot/kernel/kernel" is one obvious way.  "kldstat -v" and looking at the "size" field is another.